# location of different color of linear-gradient

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

Using `background: linear-gradient( to bottom, #fff, #ff0, #f00, #000)` sets its background equally

[image]

Can I give a location value to those colors as I can achieve as this using css3

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use units like `%` or `px` to separate them

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dHYnC/) (Not that sharp, but you can fiddle it to match your requirements)

```
background: #fffea1;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fffea1 1%, #fb8000 45%, #df0000 59%, #3f0000 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#fffea1), color-stop(45%,#fb8000), color-stop(59%,#df0000), color-stop(100%,#3f0000));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #fffea1 1%,#fb8000 45%,#df0000 59%,#3f0000 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #fffea1 1%,#fb8000 45%,#df0000 59%,#3f0000 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fffea1 1%,#fb8000 45%,#df0000 59%,#3f0000 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #fffea1 1%,#fb8000 45%,#df0000 59%,#3f0000 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fffea1', endColorstr='#3f0000',GradientType=0 );
```

Here's an [handy tool](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to create complex gradients with ease